# how to bind an html element to vo in spring with out using input type hidden

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, hidden

in my application, i am showing text in td, but I need to bind it using name attribute.
I don't want to use input type hidden. I have tried output element of HTML5, but IE doesn't support it.

Comment: Whenever someone says "I don't want to use X", it is necessary to explain why, so that alternative solutions don't suffer from the same problem.

Comment: I don't want to use input type hidden because by doing so I am including one more element which will increase the size of code(I am already using this at so many places in my code so want to improve quality of application).

Comment: why do you need to bind text that is not editable?  Can you not just use c:out to print the text from the model attribute?

Comment: I want to save that text into another table on submit of form.